# JEditorPane - make tabs spaces

Tags: java, tabs, spaces, jeditorpane

I'm wondering if there's a way to have tabs convert to spaces in a jeditorpane, much like you'd see when working in an IDE. I don't want to set the tab *size*. I can already do that easily.

I want to have tabs replaced with their equivalent in spaces. So for example if my tabs are 5 spaces long, I would want all tabs replaced immediately with 5 spaces whenever they are created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a `DocumentFilter` to the `AbstractDocument` to replaces tabs with spaces as text is inserted into the `Document`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information.

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TabToSpaceFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attributes)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        replace(fb, offset, 0, text, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attributes)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        //  In case someone tries to clear the Document by using setText(null)

        if (text == null)
            text = "";

        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text.replace("\t", "    "), attributes);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) textArea.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new TabToSpaceFilter() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Integer Filter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout( new java.awt.GridBagLayout() );
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(textArea) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also set your own Document, to transform all tabs to spaces. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setDocument%28javax.swing.text.Document%29

Comment: Yes you can use a custom Document but the preferred approach is to use the DocumentFilter. A filter can be used on any AbstractDocument so the code is more reusable and can therefore be used on a JTextArea or a JTextPane.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using a DocumentFilter - that way like camickr said once I have it all set up, I can easily replicate the behaviour later for another text field so long as it extends AbstractDocument.